# Update database partially by patch, django rest framework

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have my `CustomUser` model which extend `AbstractUser`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    detail = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)  
    pass
```

then now I want to update only `detail` column.

in javascript through patch request like this below.

```
 var formData = new FormData();
 var status = {
     fileObj:this.fileObj.id
 }
 console.log("syncdata to user table",status);
 console.log("syncdata for user:",request);
 formData.append("detail",JSON.stringify(status));
 axios.patch(
     `/api/customusers/3/`,formData,{
     }
 ).then(function (response) {
     console.log("syncdata customuser is saved:",response); 
 })
 .catch(function (response) {
     console.log("syncdata customuser failed:",response);
 });
```

this through `<QueryDict: {'detail': ['{"fileObj":19}']}>` as `request.data`

in views.py

```
class CustomUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = s.CustomUserSerializer   
    queryset = m.CustomUser.objects.all()

    def update(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        print("custom user update")
        print(request.data) // <QueryDict: {'detail': ['{"fileObj":19}']}>
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance,data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.perform_update(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors) // check error.
```

However `serializer` returns the error,

```
{'username': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}
```

What I want to do is just update the `detail` field only, but it require the `username`.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Mixin class that implements update and partial update in ModelViewSet.

```py
class UpdateModelMixin:
    """
    Update a model instance.
    """
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When receiving HTTP `PATCH` method request, DRF will call your `partial_update` method.Then the `serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)` serializer in the `update` method judges whether it is a partial update through the `partial` parameter. So to solve your problem, you just need to rewrite your `update` method as:

```py
def update(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    print("custom user update")
    print(request.data) // <QueryDict: {'detail': ['{"fileObj":19}']}>
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance,data = request.data, partial=partial)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    else:
        print(serializer.errors) // check error.
```

Comment: I can solve it, adding partial in `get_serializer`. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation!!  I see, this happens because of `Mixin` class. This answer helps me  very much  to understand.